# Audio sounds muffled/muted - but not all of it

Tags: audio, video, aac, interference

I'm viewing an MP4 file with AAC audio, and am experiencing something weird with the audio: I do hear audio; but while the background music seems to sound ok, the characters' speech and other audio effects like thuds or whooshes etc are heard at a much lower volume than they should, with a sort of a "muffling" effect.

I should mention that this doesn't happen to me with other files (including with the same format); nor when listening to audio via my browser, e.g. on PeerTube. But this *has* happened to me with another video file about a week back. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting my audio cable, to no effect.

What could be causing this? And - how can I overcome/fix it?

Additional information (ask if something is missing):

- Result of `file` on the AAC file: `MPEG ADTS, AAC, v4 LC, 48 kHz, surround + LFE`.
- Audio channels: If I understand correctly, it's "5.1"
- OS: GNU/Linux Devuan Beowulf and Gnome MPV 0.14

Comment: Is it a multichannel (5.0, 5.1 or 7.1) audio file? I've had some files mess up on a particular "surround" headset with somewhat similar effects so it could be a weird sound card driver problem.

Comment: @Mokubai: It's a 5.1 file. Can I tweak something in the audio stack to account for that?

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint from @Mokubai, I opened up pavucontrol, and looked at the 'Configuration' pane. My "Built-in Audio" entry said: "Analog Surround 5.1 Output". Well, I don't have Surround Sound; I have 2 speakers and a subwoofer, which connect to the regular single analog audio out connector.

I decided to change the value to "Analog Stereo Output". That did not bring the audio to a reasonable level, but seems to have equalized the volume of the background and foreground sound to a less-muted level. So that's a partial solution at least.